# How to switch between uiViews from a non UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, selectedindex

So here's the situation. I have an app which presents a tabBarController as its root view controller, with a number of tabItems. So here's the setup in my app delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let vc1 = VC1(nibName: "VC1", bundle: nil)
        let vc2 = VC2(nibName: "VC2", bundle: nil)

        let menuTabBarController = MenuTabBarController(nibName: "MenuTabBarController", bundle: nil)
        menuTabBarController.viewControllers = [VC1,VC2]

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = menuTabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //Setup tab bar
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let IMG1 = UIImage(named: "img2.png")
        let IMG2 = UIImage(named: "img2.png")

        VC1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "View 1",
            image: IMG1,
            tag: 1)
        VC2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
            title: "View 2",
            image: IMG2,
            tag:2)



        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    }


}
```

So notice I have two UIViewController classes(VC1 and VC2) nested within the menuTabBar.  Now from menuTabBar class, I can easily switch between the views like so

```
    class MenuTabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate{

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.delegate = self//Set tabbarcontroller delegate

        }

        // UITabBarControllerDelegate
        func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;//Say I wanted to transition to VC2
        }

    }
```

But What I ultimately want to do is to be able to switch between the two UIViewControllers from another class that is not a UIViewController. I attempted something like this

```
    class Actions(){
        func someFunctionThatSwitchesToVC2(){
            //So I create a reference to appDelegate which in turn, is supposed to reference the tab bar and switch between its child views

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let tabBarController: UITabBarController = (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)!
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }
```

When I run the someFucntionThatSwitchesToVC2, I get this error "fatal error: Index out of range".  Obviously I'm not doing something right. Any ideas greatly appreciated
PS, When I do tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0, I don't get the error but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing typo while assigning ViewControllers. Change this line:

```
menuTabBarController.viewControllers = [VC1,VC2]
```

with below line:

```
menuTabBarController.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2]
```

Comment: Apurv you are right about that. But that's not where the problem is.  This is just a miniaturized version of my actual code